# PhoneAuthProvider.credential is not a function - Firebase V9 Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase phone number verification with Next.js and Node.js.

This method is used to send code.

```
const sendVerificationCode = async () => {
        try {
            const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
            const auth = getAuth();
            const confirmationResult = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, user.phoneNumber, appVerifier);
            setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
            toast.success('Verification code sent to your phone');
        } catch (e) {
            toast.error(e.message);
        }
}
```

And when user enters the code, code and verificationId from above method is sent to backend.

```
const submitVerificationCode = async (values) => {
        try {
            await axios.post('/users/verify-phone', {code: values.code, verificationId}, {headers: {Authorization: user.token}});
            toast.success('Your phone verified');
        } catch (e) {
            toast.error(e.message);
        }
    }
```

On the backend, I'm trying to use PhoneAuthProvider.credential method.

```
exports.verifyPhone = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {verificationId, code} = req.body;

        const credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);

        const {user: {uid}} = await signInWithCredential(credentials)

        await User.updateById(uid, {phoneVerified: true})

        res.status(200).json({message: "Phone verified successfully!"})
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
}
```

Firebase package has this method in the .d.ts files.
[image]

Firebase has an example of this method [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider):
[image]

But when the code is executed, I get this error in the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the application before use. It would work if  `getAuth();` inserted before this line:
`const credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, code);`